# Error configuring the RAD WAS Portal runtime for a new server instance

Tags: websphere-portal, ibm-rad

I have installed IBM Rational Application Developer version 9.1 from the installation media.  The media launches and installs the IBM Installation manager and I've selected the RAD 9.1 package for install.  Among the options, I've requested that the "WebSphere Application Server v8.5" be installed, as well as the "WebSphere Portal Server v8.5" and all the options underneath.

Once I launch RAD, I go to the server tab (as instructed by the IBM Portal Developer course) and attempt to create a new WebSphere Portal server.  The server wizard wants to know where the installation directory of the server runtimes are located for both WAS 8.5 and Portal 8.5.

For WAS this is simple, I point to the profile "AppSrv01" at the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v85_stub\profiles\AppSrv01
```

For the Portal Server, I assume there would be a default profile created, but there is not.  There are several directories inside the stub directory, but no profiles.  The best I can do is provide the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\portal_v85_stub
```

Seems straightforward right?  It complains of the following problem:

```
The Portal Server installation directory is not correct
```

Am I missing something here?  Are there fix packs I need?  Is the portal server runtime included with RAD 9.1 not enough to create and use a local portal server?  DO I need to simply create a profile and if so where is the tool needed to do so? (I really really wish someone from IBM would explain this to me and *how I am supposed to be indicated to the correct course of action*)

IBM is, as usual, being very straightforward and easy to use/understand.  Does anyone have any ideas about how I am supposed to proceed?  The IBM Developer course that was bought and paid for assumes this step already and before you suggest it, yes I've already sent and am awaiting a response from the organization I am taking the course from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I'm getting your description right. From what I can see, you installed RAD using IM from a media. Also, you selected WebSphere Application Server development tools and all underneath it as well as WebSphere Portal development tools.

These development tools options are stubs only, not the actual servers. With this I mean  that they're useful for development and compiling purposes only, but not for deployment and testing because they are not the actual servers.

Here is the part that I don't understand. In the media that has IM and RAD, does it also have WebSphere Application Server and Portal Server available for installation? If not, then you need to get them and install them and then your can create the servers pointing to the install location of both servers in RAD. Once you do this, you can use RAD to create the profiles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Victor, then this seems correct - I did not realize that what was installed was not good enough for local test/deployment.  I got the WAS installed and can test and deploy to that, but no portal.  Yes I have the separate install disks for the Portal Server

Comment: Second follow up question - once I get the separate portal server instance installed, can I create a server in RAD and point that server to the Portal Server instance?  Or am I missing a completely separate package for RAD/Portal development?

Comment: Yes, once the Portal server and the development tools are installed (which you mention you already have) you can point RAD to it and use it as a regular server.

Comment: Thank you sir, IBM products are not always the easiest to navigate.  I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

A few things, Install portal by itself and DO NOT install to a C:\Program Files make it something short like c:\IBM\WebSphere
it sounds like only portal stub got installed, did you have the portal media available as well.
If you install it using the same installation manager, RAD will be able to find it